# Install sccm reporting role unable to connect sql (invalid connection string)

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, reporting, sccm

I am trying to install the Reporting role In SCCM but I have a lot of issues while trying to connect to the reporting server because I dont know about SQL :( ..

[image]

The reporting role is installed in a diferent server than the sccm and is working fine, there is acces to the https and http urls.

I have dissabled the firewall in both server for testing purposes but I am getting a message that says the conection string is not valid.

[image]

I have tested setting up the reporting database name or the SCCM database name but y cant get along the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When install a Reporting Services point on a remote Site System, you need to be sure that the Report server must host SQL Reporting Service. Reporting Services connects to the Configuration Manager site database to retrieve data that is returned when you run reports. So in your screenshot above:

- **Site Database Server Name**: Your site database Server Name (If not default instance, specify instance name)
- **Database Name**: Your site Server database Name

Typically the wizard automatically retrieves the site database server FQDN and SQL database name.

- **Reporting Services Server Instance**: Reporting service instance Name on remote server
- **User Name**: Specify a account that Reporting Service use to connect to Site Database to retrieve data.

If you go through Microsoft Website, you'll get full detailed step by step guide at: [InstallReportingServicesPoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712698.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_InstallReportingServicesPoint)

Comment: Is this answer helpful to answer your question?